# in google-apps-script is there a way to get to know if a google drive's folder is empty?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I would like to write a google apps script to trash every empty folder into my google drive, which method / property should I use to examine the current folder (I can write a cycle) is really empty, id est without any file or any other nested folder inside?

And, what happens if you trash a folder which has some files linked to? Do those files get trashed to or do they get orphaned (if linked to just on folder, of course)?

Thank you.

– cordialmente,

tiziano solignani, da  Mac
http://blog.solignani.it

This is what I coded after the first useful answer, I just inserted pagination:

```
function FindEmptyFolders() {

var pageSize = 200;
var folders = null;
var token = null;
var i = null;

Logger.clear()

do {
var result = DocsList.getAllFoldersForPaging(pageSize, token);
folders = result.getFolders();
token = result.getToken();
  for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
      for(n=0;n<folders.length;++n){
        if(folders[n].getFiles().length==0 && folders[n].getFolders().length==0){
            folders[n].setTrashed(true)
            Logger.log(folders[n].getName())
            Logger.log(folders[n].getUrl())
        }
      }    
  } 
 } while (folders.length == pageSize);

  MailApp.sendEmail('solignani@solignani.it', 'Script eliminazione folders vuoti Log', Logger.getLog());

}
```

Comment: Nice development:-)  I'll put that in my script collection...

Comment: Thank YOU. This raises an error, though, when getting a file you are not owing, Ill have to insert an if statement checking for ownership in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code does the job

```
function testForEmptyFolders() {
var folders = DocsList.getAllFolders()
  for(n=0;n<folders.length;++n){
    if(folders[n].getFiles().length==0 && folders[n].getFolders().length==0){
     folders[n].setTrashed(true)
     Logger.log(folders[n].getName())
     }
   }
}
```

The logger shows the names of the deleted folders

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try it asap. I just wonder what happens when there are no files but there is a nested folder, maybe with a file inside it. I just wouldn't like to lose that data. Any idea? Thanks again...

Comment: the script takes care of that as well... look at the condition that has 2 parts : no files && no folders

Comment: Sorry I did not notice the second part. Thank you I will give it a try. Thanks again.

Comment: PS I guess I will have to use pagination, for I have many files.

Answer (score 0):

The `hasNext()` method is handy here. Returns true if there's a next value in the FolderIterator or FileIterator.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator#hasNext()

```
function isEmptyFolder(folderId) {
  const folders = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFolders();
  const files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();

  if(folders.hasNext() || files.hasNext()) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }
}
```