# Automatically Delete Files from Google Shared Drive Older than X days?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive, gdrive

I'm trying to delete files and folders older than 10 days in a specific Team Drive (not in the whole Google Drive).

To accomplish this I tried to merge what I [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51596179/automatically-delete-files-from-google-drive-older-than-n-days-getfolderbyid#)

I tried to run the below script on **Google app script**. while running the script i am getting this error

`Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier line: 10 file: Code.gs`

I'm stuck with 'getFolderById' function.thats what in the line 10.

```
function deleteOldFiles() {
  var Folders = new Array(
    'YOUR-TEAM-DRIVE-ID' //you can find this in the team drive url
  );
  var DaysRetentionNumber = 15; //how many days old your files and folders must be before getting deleted?
  var RetentionPeriod = DaysRetentionNumber * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

  Logger.clear();

  for each (var FolderID in Folders) {
    folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FolderID);
    processFolder(folder);
  }

  function processFolder(folder){
    Logger.log('Folder: ' + folder.getName());
    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      Logger.log('File: ' + file.getName());
      if (new Date() - file.getLastUpdated() > RetentionPeriod) {
        //file.setTrashed(true); //uncomment this line to put them in the trash
        //Drive.Files.remove(file.getId()); //uncomment this line to delete them immediately; CAREFUL!
        Logger.log('File '+ file.getName() + ' trashed');
      }
    }
    var subfolders = folder.getFolders();
    while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
      subfolder = subfolders.next();
      processFolder(subfolder);
    }
    checkEmptyFolder(folder);
  }

  function checkEmptyFolder(folder){
    if(!folder.getFiles().hasNext() && !folder.getFolders().hasNext()){
      Logger.log('Empty folder: '+ folder.getName());
      folder.setTrashed(true); // put them in the trash
    }
  }

  if(Logger.getLog() != '')
     MailApp.sendEmail('youremailaddresshere', 'Team Drive weekly cleanup report', Logger.getLog()); //get a log in your email so that you can see what will be deleted; try this before uncommenting the trash/delete lines!
}
```

How can I modify this script to delete all team drive files older than 10 days ?

I tried [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618964/apps-script-automatically-delete-files-from-google-drive-older-than-3-days-g). but nothing worked  for Google team drives

Comment: try doing a file.list to be sure you even have access to that folder sounds you might not

Comment: its a shared drive. yes i have access to that folder.

Comment: `Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier line: 11 file: Code.gs`

this is the error which i am getting while saving the code

Comment: for each is not used in es6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function delFilesInFolderOlderThanXday() {
  const folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('id');
  const files=folder.getFiles();
  const dt=new Date();
  const threshold=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()-X).valueOf();
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    let file=files.next();
    let dtv=new Date(file.getLastUpdated()).valueOf();
    if(dtv<threshold) {
      Drive.Files.remove(file.getId(),{supportsAllDrives:true});
    }  
  }
}
```

You will have to enable Drive API if you wish to delete.  Otherwise you can put them in trash with DriveApp. You will also have to set X.

> I tested this code as of Feb 4, 2022 and it is still working

Actually to be clear I tested this code because I just wanted to make sure that Drive.Files.remove() was still working:

```
function delFilesInFolderOlderThanXday() {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('11wTZxbF9r-WlMK1uJlbcbmol7UcDV2X1');
  const files = folder.getFiles();
  const dt = new Date();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    Drive.Files.remove(file.getId(), { supportsAllDrives: true });
  }
}
```