# Delete old files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I need help creating a Google Drive script that will automatically delete all old files except the 24 most recent files.

My network drive every hour sends to Google Drive packed 7z of a database file named:

```
DATABASENAME_01.09.2017_07.bak.7z
```

and in general the format:

```
DATABASENAME_DD.MM.RRRR_HH.bak.7z
```

The files on Google Drive are copied directly (I do not have any folders).
I would like the files to be deleted instead of being moved to the trash. It's about releasing space.

I wanted to employ [other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628895/automatically-delete-files-in-google-drive) described on Stackoverflow, but they don't fulfill my requirements.

From what I've learned, the script does not work because it uses the old Doclists function. Unfortunately I do not know the programming language that is used in script.google

Answer (score 4):

I think that the best way is by using the [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) api.

There are some functions that you should use:

- [`getFiles`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbytypemimetype) allows you to select all drive files
- the `FileIterator` you receive must be sorted on the basis of [`getDateCreated()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getdatecreated)
- remove the oldest file with the [`removeFile`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#removefilechild) api OR set the oldest file as trashed with the `setTrashed` api. You can empty the trash with `Drive.Files.emptyTrash()` (this is in the Advanced Api). A we will see this method does not actually remove the file completely, and will lead to unexpected results.
- **Working approach**: it is necessary to pass through the [advanced API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) `Drive.Files` (Please read carefully how to enable the Advanced API in your script). This allows to create also a faster query for the files that you want to delete (a query that already organize them for us)

This is more or less what I would do to solve your problem:

```js
// Get all the files
files_iterator = DriveApp.getFilesByType("application/7z-compressed");

var file_list = [];
while (files_iterator.hasNext()) {
  var fl = files_iterator.next();
  file_list.push(fl); 
}

// Sort the files on date created
file_list = file_list.sort(function(fl1, fl2) {
  return fl1.getDateCreated() < fl2.getDateCreated();
});

// Removing uneeded file
while (file_list.length > 24) {
  var fl = file_list.pop();
  DriveApp.removeFile(fl);
}
```

This code is not tested and probably contains error. Use it at your own risk.

Another solution if Mime Type does not work is to list all files in your Drive and keep only the one with filename starting with `DATABASENAME`:

```
var files_iterator = DriveApp.getFiles();

var file_list = [];
while (files_iterator.hasNext()) {
  var fl = files_iterator.next();
  if (fl.getName().match("DATABASENAME"))
    file_list.push(fl); 
}
```

#### More stable version

I've written a new version that seems to work correctly:

```
function myFunction() {
  // Query drive for the files that has name containing "DATABASENAME" as prefix
  // the result (items) is ordered by creating date
  var files = Drive.Files.list({
    q: 'title contains "DATABASENAME"', 
    orderBy: 'createdDate'
  }).items;
  // While keeping the last 24 elements, runs a function
  // for each element of the Array
  files.slice(0, -25).forEach(function(file) {
    // Deletes the file (recognized with its ID)
    Drive.Files.remove(file.id)
  });
}
```

**This function does not work if you don't enable advanced API**. I've tested multiple times and only the last 24 elements remains. You **HAVE TO WAIT** that the function ends its execution before running it again, or the Arrays may become inconsistent and the second execution may delete unwanted files. Depending on the number of files in your drive account, the `list` function (as the `getFiles` function) performs queries that are **counted** and **limited**. This operations are quite expensive and running it every hour may bring you to exceed the quota. I suggest you to run this function **once a day**.

A nice thing about `list` is that actually it allows you to search by means of string of the `7z` mimeType (`"application/x-7z-compressed"`):

```
Drive.Files.list({
  q: 'mimeType = "application/x-7z-compressed"'
});
```

#### Deprecated First Version with DriveApp

This is a version that I have actually tested in my AppScript and on my Drive:

```
function myFunction() {
  var file_iterator = DriveApp.getFiles();

  var file_list = [];
  while (file_iterator.hasNext()) {
    var fl = file_iterator.next();
    if (fl.getName().match("DATABASENAMES"))
      file_list.push(fl); 
  }

  // Sort the files on date created
  file_list = file_list.sort(function(fl1, fl2) {
    return fl1.getDateCreated() < fl2.getDateCreated();
  });

  // Removing uneeded file
  while (file_list.length > 24) {
    var fl = file_list.pop();
    // fl.setTrashed(true); // if you want it in the trash
                            // instead of fully removed.
    DriveApp.removeFile(fl);
  }
}
```

but the problem with this version is that **actually does not remove the file from the drive**. I don't understand why this function exists actually, I don't see its usage. It only removes the files from the **view**

Comment: I inserted your code to the function I get an error:
TypeError: The getFilesByMimeType function can not be found in the Drive object

I changed the function to getFilesByType (mimeType) where mimeType is "application / x-7z-compressed"

The function after the change does not show any errors, but nothing happens to the files on the google drive.

Comment: So probably the mime type "application/x-7z-compressed" does not exist in Google Drive. Unfortunately, you have to derive a strategy to list all the files that you need, for example, you may list all the files in yout root and push in the file list all the files with names that begins with "DATABASENAME".

Comment: You made an error in the code in the name of the defined element: file_iterator. However, the script still does not work. It does not delete files. Of course I typed in the correct database name. There is no error when running the script.

Comment: I have just tested it in my Drive and it works: removes files without leaving in trash... There was a mistype on length (it was written as lenght... uff)

Comment: I have observed some error. How to run the script first - it worked correctly (24 files left). As I turned on the schedule for the script - executing every hour, it turns out that it removes more than 24 files. I ran several scripts manually - it deleted all files. Sorry to see this now, but as I mentioned - the first time the script worked perfectly.I want the script to delete files and to always have the 24 most recent files.

Comment: the new version has been tested against multiple call. It leaves 24 elements.