# Delete all but x most resent files in a folder Google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a folder where I store backup files and I want to keep only the 5 most recent files

All files are in a folder called `New Project Backups`

All files have `New Project` as part of their name

I found this here
[Delete old files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45996940/delete-old-files)

How do I focus the Function to look in only the folder `New Project Backups`

Thanks

```
function myFunction() {
  var file_iterator = DriveApp.getFiles();

  var file_list = [];
  while (file_iterator.hasNext()) {
    var fl = file_iterator.next();
    if (fl.getName().match("New Project"))
      file_list.push(fl); 
  }

  // Sort the files on date created
  file_list = file_list.sort(function(fl1, fl2) {
    return fl1.getDateCreated() < fl2.getDateCreated();
  });

  // Removing uneeded file
  while (file_list.length > 5) {
    var fl = file_list.pop();
    // fl.setTrashed(true); // if you want it in the trash
                        // instead of fully removed.
    DriveApp.removeFile(fl);
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `DriveApp.getFiles()` will get you all files in the drive. you can fix that by replacing

```
  var file_iterator = DriveApp.getFiles();
```

with

```
  id = "0XrUxpDX-E8dpeE9EQmpYLeplOLB";
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
  var file_iterator = folders.getFiles();
```

the `id` is the folder id you want to work with, you can find it from the folder URL

Example,
Folder URL: `https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/0XrUxpDX-E8dpeE9EQmpYLeplOLB`
Folder ID: `0XrUxpDX-E8dpeE9EQmpYLeplOLB`

enjoy ;)